# all values less than x in bst (scheme)

Tags: tree, scheme, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Someone said that this question is a duplicate. I looked at the other question and it's a different programming language from scheme.

I'm trying to write a function (lessthan x tree) that will display all the nodes in tree less than or equal to x.

I have an old code that returns the smallest value of a tree but I don't know how to return a list of values? And this looks only at the left of a tree. How do I have it look in both subtrees (left and right)?

```
(define (bst-smallest bs-tree)
  (cond ((null? bs-tree)
     '())
    ((null? (bst-left bs-tree))
     (bst-value bs-tree))
    (else
     (bst-smallest (bst-left bs-tree)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to iterate over the tree (I'll use [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) to preserve the order) and accumulate in a list all the elements that happen to be less than or equal to the given value. Notice that the second condition takes advantage of the tree's order to avoid traversing elements on the tree that are necessarily greater than the one we're looking for:

```
(define (bst-lte bs-tree value)
  (cond ((null? bs-tree)                     ; if tree is empty
         '())                                ; return empty list
        ((> (bst-value bs-tree) value)       ; if current element > value
         (bst-lte (bst-left bs-tree) value)) ; go to the left
        (else                                ; else advance recursion
         (append                             ; `append` the result
          (bst-lte (bst-left bs-tree) value) ; traverse the left subtree
          (list (bst-value bs-tree))         ; add it to the answer
          (bst-lte (bst-right bs-tree) value))))) ; traverse the right subtree
```

Comment: But the whole point of a BST is that the elements are ordered. So you can stop the traversal once you see an element that's greater.

Comment: This really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to return a list of value directly. It would make a lot more sense to build a tree first.

Think about your base cases. Calling input tree iTree and target value x

1. iTree is empty -- return the empty tree.
2. The iTree node is greater than x -- recur on the left tree
3. Otherwise build a tree with the node of iTree, the left tree of iTree on the left and the right tree the recursion on the right tree of iTree.

   ```
    (define (lessthan x tree)
         (define (helper itree)
           (cond ((empty? itree) empty-tree)
                 ((> (node itree) x) (helper (left-tree itree)))
                 (else (make-tree (node itree) 
                                  (left-tree itree) 
                                  (helper (right-tree itree))))))
                 (tree->list (helper tree)))
   ```

This is not working code, but should be easy enough to adapt to your implementation.